# how to add index.row to my function using Swift3 and Xcode8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

Can any one help me to add index.row to the function loadData(),I have a table view that I'am download my data inside it and I'am trying to view this data in another table view using loadData function , I know that I can make it inside the function of didSelectedRow but now I need to use it inside a function. I'am trying to add the row with the index to view different data .

This is my Table View.

```
 import UIKit

 class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var index = 0

var  womenArray = [women]()
var data : [String] = []
let backendless = Backendless()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    data = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)



    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}



func loadData(){

  if index == 0 {    // Here where I'am trying to put if index.row == 0

        let whereClause = "Desc = 'test'"
        let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
        dataQuery.queryOptions.pageSize=50
        dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

        backendless.data.of(women.ofClass()).find(dataQuery,response: {(result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in


            let data = result?.getCurrentPage()

            for obj in data! as! [women] {

                self.womenArray.append(obj)

            }
            let SubWomenView: WomenSubTableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subwomen") as! WomenSubTableViewController

            SubWomenView.subWomenArray = self.womenArray

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SubWomenView, animated: true)



            },

                                                  error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in

                                                    print(fault)

                                                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "info", message:"يرجى الاتصال بالانترنيت", preferredStyle: .alert)

                                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in


                                                    })

                                                    self.present(alert, animated: true){}


        })





    }else if index == 1 {

        let whereClause = "Desc = 'test2'"
                    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
                    dataQuery.queryOptions.pageSize=50
                    dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

                    backendless.data.of(women.ofClass()).find(dataQuery,response: {(result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in


                        let data = result?.getCurrentPage()

                        for obj in data! as! [women] {

                            self.womenArray.append(obj)

                        }
            let SubWomenView: WomenSubTableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subwomen") as! WomenSubTableViewController
            SubWomenView.subWomenArray = self.womenArray
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SubWomenView, animated: true)



                        },

              error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in



            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "info", message:"يرجى الاتصال بالانترنيت", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in


         })

            self.present(alert, animated: true){}


          })







    }

}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



   self.loadData()

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could pass the `indexPath` into your `loadData()` function.  Your function would then look like

```
func loadData(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        /// etc etc
    }
}
```

and in `didSelectRowAt` just call `self.loadData(at: indexPath)`